# EC2 startup script?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, startup-scripts

We're using Amazon's 32-bit Linux AMI.  What is the best way to automatically run a script after the OS is loaded (*not* on ssh login, just after it has booted up)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the command in `/etc/rc.local`.